# $rootScope.$broadcast is not updating on page reload?

Tags: angularjs, scope, broadcast, rootscope

First Controller:

`$rootScope.$broadcast("CallParentMethod", {});`

Second Controller:

```
$rootScope.$on("CallParentMethod", function() {
    $scope.getUserDetails();
})
$scope.getUserDetails = function() {
    HttpService.get("/customer/" + nationalId).then(function(resp) {
        if (resp.status == 'success') {
            console.log(resp.result)
            $rootScope.county_name = angular.copy(resp.result.county)
            $rootScope.campaign_name = angular.copy(resp.result.campaign)
            console.log($rootScope.campaign_name)
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Provide a working code snippet. Please read [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a mix of `$scopes` there

there is this event fired

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("CallParentMethod", {});
```

therefore you should be listening for this event in a child $scope, but you're listening to it in `$rootScope`

```
$rootScope.$on("CallParentMethod", function() {
    $scope.getUserDetails();
})
```

you might  want to listen for it in the same scope in which `getUserDetails()` is defined

```
$scope.$on("CallParentMethod", function() {
    $scope.getUserDetails();
})
```

Another hint: if you don't need to pass any parameters, you can ignore the empty object `{}` when `$broadcasting`

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("CallParentMethod")
```